# Heroku does not display images and also is not accepting my authentication User/Pass for access..How can I access my images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my exhisting project to Heroku. My main pages display some images, which have not loaded on heroku ..... And my backend end authentication pages , accessible only by me, will not accept my user/pass.

images are stored in 
app/assets/images

Comment: It's always nice when you actually include a question.

Answer (score 0):

Several points for you

---

**Images**

Heroku runs an [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), which essentially means your files are overwritten each time you push a new deploy.

This doesn't matter for `asset` based images, but if you're using the likes of `Paperclip` to store dynamically-uploaded images, you need to ensure you're able to persist the data (with the likes of `S3`)

--

**Precompilation**

In your case, the problem will *likely* be to do with the [*precompilation*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) process:

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.

Precompilation of the assets is when the Rails application will serve assets from the `/public` directory, rather than the `/assets` dir. This is *super* important as it means if you're referencing assets using "static" CSS references, it simply won't work, especially on Heroku

The best solution for this is to use one of the Rails [`preprocessors`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) (`SCSS` / `SASS`) & use one of the [`asset path helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) to reference the dynamic asset location:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
body {
   background: asset_url("your_image.png");
}
```

--

**Authentication**

Your authentication is probably a problem with your database

A problem with Heroku is that as it uses a different database than your local system, you'll have to populate it with the data required to get it working.

It's a common issue to not be able to load the database correctly, missing out many different migrations. I would recommend the following:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

After this, you need to ensure that you're able to create the relevant details in your application